# I'm try to share text on Whatsapp in wp8

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-8, whatsapp

I'm try to share text on whtsapp where below method not show the whtsapp messanger.

```
 ShareStatusTask shareStatusTask = new ShareStatusTask();
            shareStatusTask.Status = jokeId;
            shareStatusTask.Show();
```

But How can i share the text on whtsapp or other messanger

Comment: Can't be done. The user must select witch share target to share the content with.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I called whatsapp from my app but I haven't tried anything with sending some data to it. You will have to check it somewhere in their documentation.

```
private async void SendWhatsAppMessage()
{
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("whatsapp:"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Share Link Task as follows-

```
ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();

shareLinkTask.Title = "Code Samples";
shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri("http://code.msdn.com/wpapps", UriKind.Absolute);
shareLinkTask.Message = "Here are some great code samples for Windows Phone.";

shareLinkTask.Show();
```

Share Link Task is a little different from Share Status Task.

In both cases your app is sending some data to share, but the other application (whatsapp in this case) must also accept the data your app is sending.

But Whatsapp currently does not support ShareLinkTask or ShareStatusTask.

You should implement these in your application code. when whatsapp starts supporting them, it will appear in the list and it will be possible to share data directly with whatsapp.